# How to access Array outside Closure?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to download images and then display them in a scroll view.

- First the links are retrieved from `Firebase` as a string
- The string is converted to an array
- `DLImageLoader` downloads image 'i' and displays it in the image view.

I tested the scroll view using local images and it works. When I use the code below I get the error 'out of index'.
I'm using Swift 3

```
    override func viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Main data").child("Home Image URLs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapString = snapshot.value as? String {



           self.imageURLsVAR = snapString

                self.imageURLs = self.imageURLsVAR.components(separatedBy: ",")

      //     self.label.text = String(self.imageURLs[1])

            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


   for i in 0..<imageURLs.count{

          let imageview = UIImageView()
       // imageview.image = homeImages[i]

            dlURL = String(imageURLs[i])


             DLImageLoader.sharedInstance().image(fromUrl: String(imageURLs[i]), imageView: imageview)

            imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageview.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imgScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imgScrollView.frame.height)

            imgScrollView.contentSize.width = imgScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            imgScrollView.addSubview(imageview)

            view.sendSubview(toBack: imgScrollView)




        }





    }









2017-02-24 22:25:20.037: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.2
2017-02-24 22:25:20.045: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-02-24 22:25:20.118 tda[1828] <Notice> [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialized
2017-02-24 22:25:20.119 tda[1828] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.3700000 started
2017-02-24 22:25:20.120 tda[1828] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2017-02-24 22:25:20.134 tda[1828] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-02-24 22:25:20.209 tda[1828] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. 
2017-02-24 22:25:20.214 tda[1828] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
correct
fatal error: Index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting images in block(Closure) so you have to write image load code also in block try this

```
override func viewDidLoad()

    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Main data").child("Home Image URLs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapString = snapshot.value as? String {



           self.imageURLsVAR = snapString

                self.imageURLs = self.imageURLsVAR.components(separatedBy: ",")

      //     self.label.text = String(self.imageURLs[1])

          for i in 0..< imageURLs.count-1{
          let imageview = UIImageView()
       // imageview.image = homeImages[i]
          dlURL = String(imageURLs[i])


          DLImageLoader.sharedInstance().image(fromUrl: String(imageURLs[i]), imageView: imageview)
            imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageview.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.imgScrollView.frame.width, height: self.imgScrollView.frame.height)
            imgScrollView.contentSize.width = imgScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            imgScrollView.addSubview(imageview)
            view.sendSubview(toBack: imgScrollView)
        }
            }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

Comment: I get the same error. Also when I added the edited code you gave, it said to add 'self' to almost everything. @varunNaharia

Comment: just run the loop as for i in 0..< imageURLs.count-1

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.  I can't access the array or variables anywhere else besides between the two curly brackets where I retrieved it. @varunNaharia

Comment: How else can I access the data from that 'block' somewhere else? @varunNaharia

Comment: how you are getting same error after changing the code, please print here the error that you are getting

Comment: okay, I think it may have been a bug with Xcode. I tried it again now and it worked but I tried it 3 more times (changing no code) and I got the same error on the 2nd time but not the 3rd. Another issue id that it's only displaying the first image and if you swipe to the left it's just blank. @VarunNaharia

Comment: If you got error write here, there is no bug with xcode there is something wrong with the data that is coming from firebase , I think it's changing and if my answer is correct please mark it as correct answer

Comment: I added the error message. It's not working 100% only 1 image is being displayed so I think it's only getting the first element of the array. (I tried the scrollView code using local images and it works properly) @varunNaharia